# Linux ubuntu desktop stuck at 100Mbps

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

i am using asus z490 strix e with linux ubuntu desktop 20.04 in my home, i am having 3 computers in size my home, 2 windows which is 1Gbps, however, i don't know why my ubuntu desktop cannot go 1Gbps. My netgear router have a orange light near the LAN port which the Lan port is connected to my linux computer, this shows the connection with ubuntu desktop is having some kind of problem, the other computers are white light which so no connection problem.

I have tried to read some website and did some google about this question, but none of them worked so far for me, i don't know what should i do next.

Here are some information from the linux desktop

Please help me

```
$ lshw -class network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: d8:3b:bf:1f:d8:03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-48-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:16 memory:4012114000-4012117fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: d4:5d:64:d1:f3:48
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=0.0.1-k duplex=full ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:91100000-911fffff memory:91200000-91203fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

```
$ uname -sr
Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
```

```
$ modinfo igc
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igc/igc.ko
version:        0.0.1-k
license:        GPL v2
description:    Intel(R) 2.5G Ethernet Linux Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     A3A387D8D54D40691E20DB3
alias:          pci:v00008086d00003100sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015F7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015F8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015F3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015F2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           igc
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        69:0F:B2:8C:24:82:6C:28:AB:28:F7:D2:E5:B8:D0:0B:2C:EF:1F:87
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

```
$ ethtool -i enp4s0
driver: igc
version: 0.0.1-k
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

```
[    6.941596] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[    9.105844] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[    9.908654] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   12.069656] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[   13.436485] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   15.597640] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[   16.488485] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   18.649627] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[   19.592486] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   21.753652] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[   22.584508] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[   24.745655] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[   24.860494] igc 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igc: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

```
dmidecode -s bios-version
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable

0403
```

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUS
    Product Name: System Product Name
    Version: System Version
    Serial Number: System Serial Number
    UUID: 07bbd1a8-1a13-d340-b6f7-d45d64d1f348
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: SKU
    Family: Default string
```

Comment: Can you paste `dmesg | grep " Link is "` command output to your original post?

Comment: Is your computer using the wireless (wifi) interface, or the wired Ethernet interface?

Comment: More than likely it's a bad ethernet cable. Are you using a cat 5e or cat 6 cable? Describe your cabling from the computer to the router/modem. Is your system overclocked? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: i just added the dmesg and dmidecode output on the above post, please check.
im using wireless wifi interface and ethernet at the same time, wifi is fine, but wired have problem. The cable is cat 5e, system is using the asus motherboard AI overclock, i didn't do any setting manually other then that.

Comment: @heynnema how to make sure my ethernet is good or not

Comment: @FedonKadifeli how is it , i can't read the output

Comment: I can't find "asus motherboard AI"... are you sure that's the correct, complete, model #? Please describe ethernet cabling from computer to router/modem.

Comment: @heynnema the overclock is not a software, instead it is a build in bios "AI overclocking utility" , you can find that here, https://www.asus.com/Microsite/motherboard/Intelligent-motherboard/AI-Overclocking.html , i am using this. For the ethernet cabling from computer to router/modem , z490 mother board <= cat5e ethernet cable => R7800 router port <= R7800 build in cable => modem <= light fiber line to internet 1Gbps plan. The router is also connected with two more windows computer at the same time, which running 1Gbps, with cables.

Comment: I was looking for a motherboard model, like "ROG Maximus or Strix Z390 gaming motherboards". Show me `sudo dmidecode -t 1`.

Comment: @heynnema i have pasted the output on the top post, please check
it is ROG STRIX Z490-E GAMING

Comment: Funny enough, ASUS choose not to fill out that information. Without a motherboard model name, I can't check on an updated BIOS for you.